# How Install pari-gp

Tags: linux, apt

How I install pari-gp (a mathemtical software) on ubuntu 18 ?
I download a tar.gz file and extract it but I dont Know how install software on ubuntu 18 !!

website of package is : https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html

Comment: It's [packaged for Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/pari-gp), as even a cursory search would have shown you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable the `universe` repository then run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt install pari-gp
```

Ubuntu :[Extra Repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/configuration.html.en)

Comment: Excuseme , I install it but how call this package ?

Comment: This is what happens when you humour help vampires...

Comment: @mosi Just type the 2 commands, it will install `pari-gp` from ubuntu repo.

Comment: @GAD3R I am newcomer in linux os , what do I after two above commands ?

Comment: @mosi By executing the 2 commands `pari-gp` should be installed in ubuntu. You don't need to extact the tar.gz and compile `pari-gp` .

Comment: @GAD3R I do but when I type pari-gp in terminal , the reply is : command not found !!

Comment: @mosi type `gp`